# Using Create-React-App with Express in production

Tags: reactjs, express, create-react-app, netlify

How do I use my react-app with express in the production mode? 
Currently I call `yarn run start` in one terminal and `node server.js` in another terminal.

This works quite well in dev-mode. I added  `"proxy"` in package.json (http://localhost:8080).

The problem is I don't know how to get it working in live-mode.
I just call `yarn build` but yeah it doesn't make sense that the server is now running ;-)

Can I solve this in a simple way?

**Some code:**

package.json

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`

server.js

```
const app = express();
app.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
  ...
});
app.listen(8080);
```

In the react-app i post data to this API with axios.

**What I get/want in dev-mode:**

Correct response from the API.

**What I want in prod-mode:**

Correct response from the API.

**What I get in prod-mode:**

Error: 404 (In my opinion, because the server is not running)

Folder structure:

```
my-app
├── build
├── node_modules
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── data
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
├── scripts
│   ├── build.js
│   ├── start.js
├── src
│   ├── components
│   │     Component1.js, Component2.js, ...
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.js
│   └── serviceWorker.js
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
├── server.js
└── README.md
```

Can i solve this problem with Lambda Functions from netlify?

This is the server script:
server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const ... require(...);

const app = express();

app.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Request:", req.body);

  let error;
  let status;
  try {
    const { token } = req.body;

    const var1 = await stripe.customers.create({
      ...
    });

    const idempotency_key = uuid();
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create(
      {...}
    );
  }

  res.json({ ... });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Other way: Is it possible to run the checkout api on a php server?

Comment: `yarn build` will give you a production version of app without involving `server`. Your  server must be running, I recommend you to deploy it.

Comment: Please share your project folder structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can I do this? I use netfliy to publish my react app with the build command: yarn build

folder structure: https://ibb.co/KV6RpXp

Comment: You will need to use either Netlify Lambda Functions or host your API on another server. All these answers trying to solve for a server deployed React app don't understand Netlify and are just confusing things. Netlify **does not** run a server on a deployed site. If you could show code for the server.js and any code it uses, it would make it easier to answer.

Comment: I updated the question and added the server.js code. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

run below command for production build

`npm run build` or `yarn build`

add below line in **server.js** file to serve client/build as static content

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
```

then add below route at end of all other api routes defined , this will send index file

```
 app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

Comment: the create-react-app is not insite of root_dir_of_project/client. 
The entry point is in /src/index.js

Comment: please add your project structure in your question

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks but node server.js is never called on netlify. I think I cannot do it this way. Do you know netlify?

Answer (score 1):

**Client:**
By `yarn build` you mean `yarn run build`. [`yarn run`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run) will execute the command specified in the `scripts` section of `package.json`. In your case it will run the `build.js` file in scripts folder. Generally, it bundles the app into static files for production. So now static files being generated must be served. This part is client for now.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    ...
  }
}
```

**Server:**
I suggest you to use [`serve-static`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/serve-static) to serve the static files with `express`.

- Install it with `yarn add serve-static`
- Use `serverStatic(root,options)`, root will be your directory with static files else by default it will send the `index.html` file.

From the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/serve-static), this can be used as in a simple way :

> ```
> var express = require('express')
> var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
>
> var app = express()
>
> app.use(serveStatic('public/ftp', { 'index': ['default.html', 'default.htm'] }))
> app.listen(3000)
> ```

There are also other variants which you can check [here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/serve-static).

For deploying your project on Heroku, follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).

Comment: I think the server.js is never called? Isn't it?

Comment: These are edits in `sever.js`. Server should be running.

Comment: About `public\ftp`, that's an example. Replace it with your directory it would be `build` where your static files are present.

Comment: Okay so my static files are in the build folder (build/index.html,...) 
So i did this:app.use(serveStatic('build/', { 'index': ['index.html'] })) -> No change, it's 404

Comment: I can change whatever I want in the server.js. There are no errors etc. How can I check that the server is running?

Comment: Aren't you running client and server separately? If yes, then check in the terminal of server, what are the logs.

Comment: No I use netlify to publish my site that just runs: yarn build

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198106/discussion-between-abhinav-kinagi-and-epus).

Comment: I followed the instructions on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote, but the server is still not running -> "Invalid Host header"